# I have a webrtc app which works fine on localhost host but it doesn't when it is live

Tags: webrtc, coturn, openwebrtc

Hello There I have a webrtc, react and node based application which is using my own configured coturn servers:

[Image Showing my Coturn servers on webrtc Trickle Ice Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3DM1.png)

The workflow is react component is getting the Ice Servers and stream and sending it to server which then receives the streams and saves it here is the code for the admin which is send the streams (I am cutting much of the code):

```
async function init() {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true });
    document.getElementById("video").srcObject = stream;
    const peer = createPeer();
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {peer.addTrack(track, stream)});
}


function createPeer() {
    const peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [
//           {
//             urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
//           },
//           {
//             urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=udp",
//             username: "admin",
//             credential: "admin",
//           },
//           {
//             urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp",
//             username: "admin",
//             credential: "admin",
//           },
//           {
//             urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=udp",
//             username: "admin",
//             credential: "admin",
//           },
//           {
//             urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp",
//             username: "admin",
//             credential: "admin",
//             },
//           {
//             urls: "stun:turn.safetixstreaming.com",
//             username: "admin",
//             credential: "admin"
//           },
          {
            urls: "turn:turn.safetixstreaming.com",
            username: "admin",
            credential: "admin"
          }
        ]
    });
    peer.onnegotiationneeded = () => handleNegotiationNeededEvent(peer);
    peer.oniceconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
      console.log('ICE Connection State Change:', peer.iceConnectionState);
  };
  
  peer.onconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
      console.log('Connection State Change:', peer.connectionState);
  };
  
  peer.onsignalingstatechange = (event) => {
      console.log('Signaling State Change:', peer.signalingState);
  };
  

    return peer;
}

async function handleNegotiationNeededEvent(peer) {
    const offer = await peer.createOffer();
    await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);
    const payload = {
        sdp: peer.localDescription
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(`https://safetixstreaming.com/broadcast/`, payload);
    const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp);
    peer.setRemoteDescription(desc).catch(e => console.log(e));
}

return (
        <h2
        style={{
        fontWeight: 'bold'
       }}
        >{title}</h2>
    <video autoPlay muted playsInline id="video"
        className='rounded'
       style={{
        display: videoElementDisplay,
        width: "70%",
        maxHeight: "auto"
       }}
    ></video>
)
```

[My Broadcaster side with its console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgd48.png)

and here is the server side code which receives the request:

```
let senderStream;
app.post(`/broadcast/`, async ({ body }, res) => {
    try {
        const peer = new webrtc.RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [
    //             {
    //                 urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
    //             },
    //             {
    //                 urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80",
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin",
    //               },
    //               {
    //                 urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp",
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin",
    //               },
    //               {
    //                 urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443",
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin",
    //               },
    //               {
    //                 urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp",
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin",
    //               },
    //                 {
    //                     urls: "stun:turn.safetixstreaming.com:3478",      
    //                     username: "admin",
    //                     credential: "admin"
    //                 },
                    {
                        urls: "turn:turn.safetixstreaming.com:3478",
                        username: "admin",
                        credential: "admin"
                    }
            ]
        });
        peer.ontrack = (e) => handleTrackEvent(e, peer);
        const desc = new webrtc.RTCSessionDescription(body.sdp);
        await peer.setRemoteDescription(desc);
        const answer = await peer.createAnswer();
        await peer.setLocalDescription(answer);
        const payload = {
            sdp: peer.localDescription
        }

        res.json(payload);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});

function handleTrackEvent(e, peer) {
    senderStream = e.streams[0];
};
```

This is the code which requests to watch the stream:

```
        async function init(id, name) {
            setLoader("flex")
            setRoomId(id)
            setText(name)
            roomID  = id;
            console.log(roomId)
    const peer = createPeer();
    peer.addTransceiver("video", { direction: "recvonly" })
}

function createPeer() {
    const peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [
  //           {
  //               urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
  //             },
  //             {
  //               urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80",
  //               username: "807973d909920f718ba0b567",
  //               credential: "VGyNVhO+WtsGoTih",
  //             },
  //             {
  //               urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp",
  //               username: "807973d909920f718ba0b567",
  //               credential: "VGyNVhO+WtsGoTih",
  //             },
  //             {
  //               urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443",
  //               username: "807973d909920f718ba0b567",
  //               credential: "VGyNVhO+WtsGoTih",
  //             },
  //             {
  //               urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp",
  //               username: "807973d909920f718ba0b567",
  //               credential: "VGyNVhO+WtsGoTih",
  //             },
  //               {
  //                 urls: "stun:turn.safetixstreaming.com",
  //                 username: "chris",
  //                 credential: "Capricorn190RCapricorn13F"
  //               },
                {
                  urls: "turn:turn.safetixstreaming.com",
                  username: "chris",
                  credential: "Capricorn190RCapricorn13F"
                }
        ]
    });
    peer.onnegotiationneeded = () => handleNegotiationNeededEvent(peer);
    peer.ontrack = handleTrackEvent;
    peer.oniceconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
      console.log('ICE Connection State Change:', peer.iceConnectionState);
  };
  
  peer.onconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
      console.log('Connection State Change:', peer.connectionState);
  };
  
  peer.onsignalingstatechange = (event) => {
      console.log('Signaling State Change:', peer.signalingState);
  };

    return peer;
}

async function handleNegotiationNeededEvent(peer) {
    const offer = await peer.createOffer();
    await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);
    const payload = {
        sdp: peer.localDescription
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(`https://safetixstreaming.com/consumer/`, payload);
    console.log("Data",data)
    const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp);
    console.log("Desc", desc)
    peer.setRemoteDescription(desc).catch(e => console.log(e));
}

async function handleTrackEvent(e) {
    console.log("Stream ", e)
    let remoteVideo = document.getElementById("video")
    remoteVideo.srcObject = await e.streams[0];
    setOtherElementDisplay("none");
    setVideoElementDisplay("block")
};


return(
      <h2
              style={{
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
              }}
      >{text}</h2>
          <video
              style={{
                  display: videoElementDisplay,
                  width: "70%",
                  maxHeight: "auto"
              }}
              autoPlay 
              muted
            //   is='x-muted'
              playsInline 
              controls
              id='video'
              ></video>
)
```

And the server side code for this is:

```
app.post(`/consumer/`, async ({ body, params }, res) => {
    try {
        // let id = params.id
        // console.log("Id", params.id)
        const peer = new webrtc.RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [
    //             {
    //                 urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
    //               },
    //               {
    //                 urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80",
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin",
    //               },
    //               {
    //                 urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp",
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin",
    //               },
    //               {
    //                 urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443",
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin",
    //               },
    //               {
    //                 urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp",
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin",
    //               },
    //             {
    //                 urls: "stun:turn.safetixstreaming.com:3478",      
    //                 username: "admin",
    //                 credential: "admin"
    //             },
                {
                    urls: "turn:turn.safetixstreaming.com:3478",
                    username: "admin",
                    credential: "admin"
                }
            ]
        });
        const desc = new webrtc.RTCSessionDescription(body.sdp);
        await peer.setRemoteDescription(desc);
        // const matchingRoom = rooms.find((room) => room.roomId === id);
        // if (matchingRoom) {
        //     console.log(matchingRoom)
        //     let stream = matchingRoom.senderStream;
        //     console.log("Selected Stream:", senderStream);
        //     stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, stream));
        // } else {
        //     console.log("No matching room found.");
        // }
        // const matchingRoom = rooms.find((room) => room.roomId === id);
        // if (matchingRoom) {
            // console.log(matchingRoom)
            let stream = senderStream;
            console.log("Selected Stream:", senderStream);
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, stream));
        // } else {
            // console.log("No matching room found.");
        // }
        const answer = await peer.createAnswer();
        await peer.setLocalDescription(answer);
        const payload = {
            sdp: peer.localDescription
        }

        res.json(payload);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

[Video Stream receiving side with the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlobD.png)

This is not my complete code and the credentials are not the real credentials.
Can Anyone kindly help me? I have stuck in this for days

Thanks

There I have a webrtc, react and node based application which is using my own configured coturn servers The app works on localhost but it doesn't when I try to run it on a web aws/hostinger based

Comment: Add try....catch to catch error from the following statement:` const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true });`

And then post the error here.

Comment: Have you installed the SSL cert. to your web server? If you haven't installed an SSL certificate on your web server, you cannot get media from the client. That is why I suggest using try....catch to catch the error for getting media from the client.

Comment: The domain with SSL that I have set up. The server is correctly pointed to the domain using nginx, I haven't encountered any problems with getUserMedia; it's functioning well and displaying the media as expected. However, I seem to be facing a challenge with the ICE connection—it appears to disconnect before even making a connection to the server. I would really appreciate any guidance or assistance you could provide on this matter.